# Help with inverse trig derivatives with L'Hopital rule

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry

so I have a problem with my teacher's notes and they have confused me. take this equation 
 \begin{align}
      \lim _{x\to0}  \frac{\arcsin x}{ \sin x} 
    \end{align}

if we do the derivative of the top and bottom using l'hopitals rule we get

\begin{align}
      (\arcsin x)'= \frac{1}{ \sqrt{1-x^2}} 
    \end{align}
\begin{align}
      (\sin x)'= \cos x 
    \end{align}

but when my teacher put them together she did't explain how she somehow got this.
\begin{align}
       \lim _{x\to0}  \frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{ \cos x} 
    \end{align}

Please help this makes no sense to me, why is the numerator no longer a fraction?

Comment: It's a typo, basically

Comment: okay so she didn't do some wizard magic to make the fraction disappear. Then would the problem still make sense if the numerator was a fraction?

Comment: Yep... your teacher is wrong.

Comment: thank goodness. thank you guys very much.

Comment: There is no point in using `align` when you are writing a single equation.

Comment: Note that your first and last "equations" are not equations and the the $=$ signs should be removed from the two expressions

Answer (score 4):

**HINT:**

Note that

$$\frac{\arcsin(x)}{\sin(x)}=\frac{\arcsin(x)}{x}\,\frac{x}{\sin(x)}$$

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that your teacher made a mistake

$$\frac{\arcsin(x)'}{\sin(x)'} = \frac{\frac{1}{\sqrt{1 -x^2}}}{\cos(x)} \cdot \frac{\sqrt{1 -x^2}}{\sqrt{1 -x^2}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 -x^2}\cos(x)}$$

Therefore

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 -x^2}\cos(x)}$$